# Gridview not scrolling properly

Tags: android, android-gridview

The gridview does not scroll properly on all phones such that the last 2 images are not displayed properly. Please let me know what's the problem. I even tried padding but its not working.

[image]

```js
This is main layout:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backg" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        
        android:src="@drawable/header1" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/TableLayout1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="#00FF0000"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#505050" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:src="@drawable/bottom1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/bottom2" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:src="@drawable/bottom3" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

```html
This is gridview_item.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="100dp">
    <com.example.myapp2.SquareImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="center"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="#55000000"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: link for MainActivity http://www.filedropper.com/mainactivity

link for SquareImageView.java  http://www.filedropper.com/squareimageview

Answer (score 0):

I added android:paddingBottom="400dp" in gridview and it looks like its working on most of the phones

```html
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/TableLayout1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="#00FF0000"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:paddingBottom="400dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>
```